# Loading 32-bit binary file (little endian) to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, io, binary

I'm trying to read and loading binary data from a 32-bit binary file (Little endian) into a numpy array but I keep on getting a list of nan's. For Computational goods, I was trying to read it in by chunks.

Some previous Posts I looked at:

1. [Reading an entire binary file into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423647/reading-an-entire-binary-file-into-python)
2. [Reading an entire binary file into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423647/reading-an-entire-binary-file-into-python)
3. [Reading a 32 bit floating point binary data file (little endian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774866/reading-a-32-bit-floating-point-binary-data-file-little-endian)
4. [How do I build a numpy array from a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367565/how-do-i-build-a-numpy-array-from-a-generator)
5. [Reading binary file and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte)

This is one sample code I used:

```
 from pathlib import Path
 from functools import partial
 from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

 def file_byte_iterator(path):
    """given a path, return an iterator over the file
    that lazily loads the file
    """
    path = Path(path)
    with path.open('rb') as file:
        reader = partial(file.read1, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        file_iterator = iter(reader, bytes())
        for chunk in file_iterator:
            for byte in chunk:
                yield byte
```

Comment: That code which you provide does nothing but define a function. Please extract a [mcve] from your code and post that here. Also note that we don't have the file you're trying to read either!

Comment: What does `np.fromfile` do?  Which dtypes have you tried?